# Is camel suitable for consuming changing ftp file?

Tags: file, apache-camel

I want to monitor change of a remote file, when adding something, transfer these added things to somewhere else line by line.

If using fileSize as idempotentKey, the file change can be detected, but the consumer always start from the beginning, cause a lot of duplicate.

So, any advice?

Comment: Apache Camel is not a file monitoring tool, it is an integration framework and usually monitoring file changes (unless for consumption) is not part of the main functionality.

Comment: What do you mean the consumer always start from the beginning? Where do you want to start it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in support for your use case - and with good reason, too: that's just not the way FTP was envisioned to work since there isn't a native FTP command that would allow you to watch a file and constantly stream new content.

But Camel can still help you avoid the manual polling - you can make your idempotent key consist of file name and file length and then manually keep track of the last line read from each file  in either a DB or an in-memory cache, depending on your use-case. Then, whenever you detect an update you only need to skip everything up to that last line and continue consuming from there.